# List files with . .. but without hidden files

Tags: files, ls

Is there a way to list all files and directories *including* `.` and `..` but without listing hidden files in this folder?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. You know those hardlinks will always be there, so what's the purpose of listing them? My only guess is that you want to parse the output of `ls`, which is a shell faux pas.

Comment: @gardenhead I have existing code that parse ls output and I need to know the current folder permissions in order to enable/disable items in the UI. is there a better way than parsing ls do list files with their permissions?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls. If you need to get the file permissions, I would recommend running `stat` on each file in a `for` loop.

Comment: For a precise example of @gardenhead's suggestion, since you mention permissions, check out `stat --format=%A .`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First ensure that dotglob is off:

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

Then just ask `ls` for those two directories and everything else:

```
ls -ld . .. *
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it could be easy to define the following as an alias for instance:

```
ls -ld \. \.\. *
```

Comment: You don't need the backslashes, the dot isn't special to the shell. (It is in regexes, but shell filename patterns aren't regexes.)